# How to enable R syntax highlighting in Jupyter?

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I am looking to add syntax highlighting for R code written in Jupyter. To be precise, syntax highlighting beyond the one that already exists for numbers, text, etc.

My setup:

- Packges

  - Conda R 3.2.4
  - Conda Version 4.0.6
  - Jupyter version 4.1.0
- Running on Windows 7 with Chrome

I see an implementation of something similar here. Not sure if it has R

https://github.com/merqurio/jupyter_themes

Any ideas are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: What is the file extension of your R files. "R" or "r"?

Comment: I was referring to the actual syntax highlighting in the notebook (.ipynb). But I checked and noticed that it's essentially the same as .r files. I was looking for richer code highlighting than the one that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use ".r" as the file extension.  Apparently ".R" does not do syntax highlighting until Jupyter 4.2 (at least the PR that adds this capability is on the 4.2 milestone).  See [this github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1073) for more info.